# activeadmin override index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, overriding, activeadmin

my problem is related to customization in ActiveAdmin.
First of all I can't get how to override index action. Everything looks simple according to the documentation but very few things work as expected. Eventually I came up with these two alternatives. First one is a [blogpost](http://blog.codingspree.net/2011/06/18/scoping_resources_in_activeadmin.html) which presents the following solution (which appear to work).

```
  scope_to do
    Class.new do
      def self.projects
        Project.where(:id => 1)
      end
    end
  end
```

While this one, which is the solution for issue#511 does not work. Can anyone tell why??

```
  scope_to :current_project

  controller do
    private
    def current_project
      Project.where(:id => 1)
    end
  end
```

What's your experience? How do you achieve index action customization?

I'm an experienced web developer but I'm new to Ruby world in general.
Do you think it's a good idea to use ActiveAdmin for a production project? What's you pick when it comes to Admin interface?
I've read about Rails Admin but looks like it's not easy to customize.

My biggest concern at the moment is about active admin not easy to customize to achieve UI or behavior which are very different from the ones that it offers by default.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize controller see https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources. For example:

```
controller do
  def index
    # something
    index! do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to some_url }
    end
  end

  protected
  def collection
    @projects ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end
```